# How to create a lambda expression for a nested generic in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I have a data structure defined as:
    `Dictionary<Guid, List<string>> _map = new Dictionary<Guid, List<string>>();`

I'm trying to create a lambda expression that given a string, returns a IEnumerable of Guids associated with any `List<string>`
containing that string.

Is this reasonable/possible or should I use a more appropriate data structure?

Thanks in advance!
Kim

Comment: Are you using the dictionary backwards? I mean you want the key given the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
Func<string,IEnumerable<Guid>> lambda = filter => (
   _map
      .Where(x => x.Value.Contains(filter))
      .Select(x => x.Key));
```

Usage

```
var keys1 = filter("foo");
var keys2 = filter("bar");
```

Comment: That's it! Just a small change in usage to:
var keys1 = lambda("foo")

Saved me a ton of time - thanks!